# Run macro in Outlook to save attachment to disk from shared inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I have full access to two shared emails on my account. I would like to run a macro on one of the shared emails inbox that saves the attachments to the hard drive. I don't want the macro to run on all items in the inbox but only the ones selected/highlighted. I am unable to get the code below to work. Can I get some advice on how to make my code work?

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk ()

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim dateFormat
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set myRecipient = objNS.CreateRecipient("invoices@domain.com")
myRecipient.Resolve
Set inbox = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)

saveFolder = "c:\temp\"

For Each itm In ActiveExplorer.Selection
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments        
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing 
    Next objAtt
Next itm
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a run time error stating object required when I run the macro.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I also had to define inbox by adding, 'Dim inbox As MAPIFolder'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks good, I don't see anything strange. But most probably you need to correct the file path (remove the double backslash):

```
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
```

Do you get any error in the code? Did you try to specify another file path?

Be aware, the C: drive requires admin privileges for writing on systems with UAC enabled.

Comment: I get an object required error. When I go into to debug it highlights:        Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"). This is a modified script that worked on my default inbox. So I'm trying to get it to work on a certain shared inbox.

Comment: Use `Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit    ' <-----

Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk()
...
End Sub
```

> Compile error:
>   Variable not defined

olApp is not defined:

```
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

If the code is in Outlook:

```
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

If not in Outlook:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
```

To automatically generate `Option Explicit` at the top of new modules:

In the VB editor. Tools menu | Options

Check "Require Variable Declaration"